# Auto call by pressing button

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to make button which allow me to make automatic call

This is how I am making call actually

```
String number = "1234";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel",number,null));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I must confirm to make call by pressing telephone icon in dialer. Is it possible to make it automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use action `Intent.ACTION_CALL`, So, Change this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel",number,null));
```

With this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel",number,null));
```

Add permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
            1);

  }
}
```

Handle permission:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] +
                    grantResults[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Call whatever you want

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`

Comment: @RamZes, ask permission at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It will help you.

```
String number = "1234";
```

Get number in Uri

```
Uri numberUri = Uri.parse("tel:"+number);
```

Code for Dial

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, numberUri);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Code for Call

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, numberUri);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

**EDIT**

In marshmallow you have to take run time permission for calling.
You can not make call if permission is denied.

Now there is other solution I want to give you.

> You can make auto call in 6.0 or above without asking for run time permission. but for this, you have to set `targetSdkVersion` to `19` or below `22`. So what will happen, that the all permission will be enable automatically because the `Android OS` will take it as old application and allow without taking it run time permission.
>
> > But there is one more problem. it will not work after disabling permission manually by going on Setting.

Comment: Call requires permissions which may be rejected

Comment: in 6.0 you have to take permission dynamically,
without permission, you can not make call auto.